# How to change prompt at terminal in ubuntu?

Tags: terminal

I would like the prompt to only have the $. 'X-terminal emulator' is being used. [image]

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. More information is available in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bash, inside your .bashrc file, do this:

```
PS1="$ "
export PS1
```